# How to set PWM using sysfs in c code for beaglebone black pinout?

Tags: c, linux, beagleboneblack, pwm

I am a beginner in `beaglebone black` and I am working on `PWM pins` on two development boards
when I export pwm0 in the first board it shows me like,

```
/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm-0\:0/
```

and when I export pwm0 in the second board it shows me like,

```
/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0/
```

I am confused now why in two `beaglebones` have a different name
anyone help me

Thanks,

Comment: For how to do it from the shell see https://www.technexion.com/support/knowledgebase/using-pwm-from-a-linux-shell/ for the shell commands that set the `period`, the `duty_cycle`, and the `enable` using the `echo` command. If you open the pseudo files, write values, and close the pseudo files using the same format as the `echo` commands, that should work.

Comment: See also https://www.acmesystems.it/pwm as well as the Linux documentation https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/pwm.html